# Programmatically trigger a copy or paste in c#

Tags: c#, .net, copy-paste

I have a program that I'm working on that register global hotkeys

I would like to use that ability to trigger highlighted text or data to be copied to the clipboard and then read from the clipboard into a variable in my program

which i will later use in reverse to paste it back out.

(example ctrl+1 copys to quque #1 and alt+1 pasts what is in quque 1)

thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SendKeys.Send("^c");
```

Comment: Link or Reference to what lib this is included in would be nice.

Answer (score 7):

You mean... like this?

```
Clipboard.SetText("whatever");
```

...or are you talking about copying text from any arbitrary window in another application? The latter is not trivial at all.

Comment: 1) yes I am talking about taking text from the global clipboard 2) i figured it would be hard to see the text highlighted on other programs (IE Firefox notepad word etc) but it woudlnt be hard to send a "copy event" to the os and have it do all the hard work for me

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could possibly do a P/Invoke with **SendMessage** or even better **SendInput** Win32 APIs. That should be enough for you to simulate almost any key strokes.

James

Comment: do you have a link to an example?